How to solve 'SQL compilation error: Object 'SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_FLGVIWVUC' already exists.' issue in snowflake?
I have been using Snowflake to do ML works.
I have built a Multiple linear regression. I am writing an output df as a table using session.write_pandas. I get this error
'SQL compilation error: Object 'SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_XXXXX' already exists.' 

in snowflake streamlit app. This goes if I refresh the page. But why it occurs? I could not find issues related to this in web.
I get this error only if i write dataframe as pandas.
Below is the code where i get this error.

from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
session = get_active_session()
session.write_pandas(df_final, "TEMPTABLE",database="db",schema="schema", auto_create_table=True, overwrite=True)

I have tried to clear or drop the stage every time before write_pandas code.
import uuid
    
# Drop the stage if it already exists
session.sql(f"DROP STAGE IF EXISTS {stage_name}").collect()

# Create a new temporary stage
session.sql(f"CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE {stage_name}").collect()

This does not work and what is the real reason I get this error?
Please help I have no idea why this happens.

Maybe try CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE IF NOT EXISTS ...

Trying to patch away two types of errors when writing from pandas Dataframe() to tables in Snowflake.

SNOWPARK_TEMP_FILE_FORMAT_XXXX already exists
SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_XXXX already exists

There is also a race condition which ever may occur first, so we have to write try-except within a try-except to resolve this issue.
This issue seen in all SNOWPARK related tools like Streamlit in Snowflake, Python-workbook and Python Stored procedures etc.
# EXAMPLE:
# Modify this fix to your own use accordingly ✅
# Snowflake may patch this BUG in the future.
# This BUG is really annoying. 

import re
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
session = get_active_session()

def try_to_write_pd_to_table(my_session, my_df, my_tablename, my_db, my_sch):
    try:
        my_session.write_pandas(my_df, my_tablename, database=f"{my_db}", schema="{my_sch}", auto_create_table=True, overwrite=True)
    except Exception as e1:
        try:
            tmp_file_format=re.findall('SNOWPARK_TEMP_FILE_FORMAT_[A-Z]{10}', str(e1))
            if(len(tmp_file_format)>0):
                my_session.sql(f'DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS {my_db}.{my_sch}.{tmp_file_format[0]};').collect();
            tmp_stage=re.findall('SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_[A-Z]{10}', str(e1))
            if(len(tmp_stage)>0):
                my_session.sql(f'DROP STAGE IF EXISTS {my_db}.{my_sch}.{tmp_stage[0]};').collect();
            my_session.write_pandas(my_df, my_tablename, database=f"{my_db}", schema="{my_sch}", auto_create_table=True, overwrite=True)
        except Exception as e2:
            tmp_file_format=re.findall('SNOWPARK_TEMP_FILE_FORMAT_[A-Z]{10}', str(e2))
            if(len(tmp_file_format)>0):
                my_session.sql(f'DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS {my_db}.{my_sch}.{tmp_file_format[0]};').collect();
            tmp_stage=re.findall('SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_[A-Z]{10}', str(e2))
            if(len(tmp_stage)>0):
                my_session.sql(f'DROP STAGE IF EXISTS {my_db}.{my_sch}.{tmp_stage[0]};').collect();
            my_session.write_pandas(my_df, my_tablename, database=f"{my_db}", schema="{my_sch}", auto_create_table=True, overwrite=True)

try_to_write_pd_to_table(session, df_final, "TEMPTABLE", 'LLM_DATABASE', 'ML_SCHEMA');


